# Predict frequency or probability based on a crosstable

Tags: probability

I have a cross table

Class -11--10--9--8--7--6--5--4--3--2--1--0

A --------5----1--0--0--0--1--2--1--0--2--0--1

B --------2----2--5--1--7--3--4--6--3--8-19-11

C --------0----2--2--0--1--0--4--0--2--1--2--6

D --------2----3--1--4--0--1--8--5--5--3-10--2

E --------0----0--0--0--0--0--0--0--1--0--0--1

[image]

Of the 13 objects that classifies as Class A, 5 associated with 11 genes, 1 with 10 genes 1 with 6 genes, 5 with 2 genes, and etc. The same is for class B, C,D, and E. Now, if I have an object that associated with 11 genes, what is the probability of this object belongs to class A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is $P(A | 11 genes)$? If you look at the first column of the table below, the answer is straightforward,

```
+--------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
| Class  |11  | 10| 9 | 8 | 7 |6  | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | RowSums |
+--------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
|   A    |   5| 1 | 0 | 0   0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 13      |
|   B    |   2| 2 | 5 | 1   7 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 3 | 8 | 19| 11| 71      |
|   C    |   0| 2 | 2 | 0   1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 20      |
|   D    |   2| 3 | 1 | 4   0 | 1 | 8 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 10| 2 | 44      |
|   E    |   0| 0 | 0 | 0   0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2       |
+--------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
|ColSums |   9| 8 | 8 | 5   8 | 5 | 18| 12| 11| 14| 31| 21| 150     |
+--------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
```

$P(A | 11 genes)$ = 5/9